# GNU make implicit rules for batch file processing

Tags: makefile, rules, implicit

I'd like to use *GNU make* to automate batch file processing, in my particular case I have a huge number of image files, I'd like to colorspace convert and reencode them to a custom file format. The file format encoder accepts only filenames on the command line, i.e. no stdio redirection.

My file and directory structure is

```
./sourceimages/*.tif
./destimages/*.mie
./Makefile
```

I wrote a peliminary Makefile with a pattern rule

```
%.mie : %.tif
    tmpraw := $(shell mktemp --suffix=raw)
    convert $< -colorspace YUV -resize …x… rgb:$(tmpraw)
    miecoder $(tmpraw) $@
    rm $(tmpraw)
```

But now I'm stuck, because I can't figure out how to make *make* to take all the files in `sourceimages` as prerequisites of implicit targets in `destimages`. So how can I do this?

I'd really like to use *make* for this, to harness its capability for parallel execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your use of `mktemp` to create a unique temporary file name is unnecessary and leads to other problems; if you're converting `foo.tif` to `foo.mie`, let's just call the temporary file `foo_temp.tif`.

```
%.mie : %.tif
    convert $< -colorspace YUV -resize …x… rgb:$*_temp.tif
    miecoder $*_temp.tif $@
    rm $*_temp.tif
```

Next, we put in the paths so that Make can build a target in one place using a prerequisite from another:

```
destimages/%.mie : sourceimages/%.tif
    convert $< -colorspace YUV -resize …x… rgb:$*_temp.tif
    miecoder $*_temp.tif $@
    rm $*_temp.tif
```

Finally we look for sources, infer a list of desired targets, then make them prerequisites of the default taget (put all of this above the `destimages/%.mie:...` rule in the makefile):

```
SOURCES := $(wildcard sourceimages/%.tif)
TARGETS = $(patsubst sourceimages/%.tif, destimages/%.mie, $(SOURCES))

.PHONY: all
all: $(TARGETS)
```

Comment: Well, unfortunately miecoder expects the input image to be a tiff and the filename being suffixed .tif, that's why the mktemp; but some static infix would work as well, though I'd prefer this to be some unique string.

Comment: Easily fixed; I've edited the answer to use `foo_temp.tif` rather than `foo.tmp`.